# PHP unable to upload .docx file type

Tags: php

I'm new to php and I can't seem to upload .docx files to the path specified.
It goes directly to invalid file type.

```
enter code here
        if(!empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
        $allowed_types = ["application/msword"];
        if(in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"], $allowed_types)) {
            $input_name = "file";
            $upload_path = "../finaid_organization/assets/documents";
            $file_name = (!empty($_FILES[$input_name]["name"]) ? basename($_FILES[$input_name]["name"]) : "");
            $file_name = "ld_".date("YmdHis").".".pathinfo($file_name)["extension"];
            $path = $this->do_upload($input_name, $upload_path, $file_name);
            $path = "/assets/documents/".$path;



            $data += ["location_path" => $path];

            $this->model_loan_doc->insert($data);

            $ret = [
                "success"   => true,
                "msg"       => "<span class='fa fa-check'></span> Success"
            ];
        } else {
            $ret = [
                "success"   => false,
                "msg"       => "<span class='fa fa-warning'></span> Invalid file type"
            ];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably added a docx document, which you have to check with a different filetype

For docx check this MIME type:

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

so your array should be:

```
$allowed_types = ["application/msword", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"];
```